# Xubuntu can't log out or use terminal

Tags: xubuntu, session

I installed Xubuntu 16.04 yesterday and today I'm finding I can't use the system.

Firefox works perfectly fine but I can't open terminal or Virtualbox.

When I try to shutdown I get the following:

```
**Received error while trying to log out**

Session manager must be in idle state when requesting a shutdown
```

Comment: To make matters worse, all the "solutions" to this problem offered historically require running commands with terminal open.